# Is there any SQL Syntax that will help me find if things are in descending order?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

An example is if I want to find the driver_ssn of each driver in this table who's exam scores get consecutively lower when they take more exams.

Sample data below:

```
Driver_ssn Branch_id Exam_date Exam_type Exam_score
11111111   20       2017-05-25     D         79
11111111   20       2017-12-02     L         67
22222222   30       2016-05-06     L         25
22222222   40       2016-06-10     L         51
22222222   40       2016-08-29     D         81
33333333   10       2017-07-07     L         45
33333333   20       2017-06-27     L         49
33333333   20       2017-07-27     L         61
44444444   10       2017-07-27     L         71
44444444   20       2017-08-30     L         65
44444444   40       2017-09-01     L         62
```

I don't have a query available to post as I am very new to SQL and don't know where to begin here.

I am on version 8.0.18

Comment: 'in this table' - what table would that be? Please add sample data (as text)

Comment: Please add your query and elaborate the issue in detail

Comment: If you are on mysql 8 or above search for RANK and DENSE_RANK. (tell us the version you are on anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested but give this a try; [returns 1111 and 4444 for the sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43fac124897d7a613d5092c09f17e04d):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT driver_ssn
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY driver_ssn ORDER BY exam_date) AS rn1
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY driver_ssn ORDER BY exam_score DESC, exam_date) AS rn2
    FROM t
)
SELECT driver_ssn
FROM cte
GROUP BY driver_ssn
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN rn1 = rn2 THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
```

Basically you number the rows for each driver by date and by score separately. If there is a pattern of increasing dates and decreasing scores then row numbers will be identical for every row.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to look more into ROW_NUMBER() OVER and PARTITION BY to understand them (unsure if there is a way to do this without them) but this helps a ton!

Comment: I like this solution. The `HAVING` clause could also be written as `having sum(rn1 <> rn2) = 0` in MySQL.

Comment: Just an observation: `ORDER BY exam_score DESC, exam_date` allows for consecutive exams with the same score. If you want to interdict them, make this `ORDER BY exam_score DESC, exam_date DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. you can use ORDER BY in your query see the example below:

```
SELECT * FROM your-table ORDER BY column-name DESC
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't give me the driver_ssn's of consecutive descending scores. I understand the ORDER BY statement but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the score with the previous score using `LAG`. Show all ssn for which not exist an exam that scored higher than the previous one using `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`.

```
select distinct driver_ssn from exams
where driver_ssn not in
(
  select driver_ssn
  from
  (
    select
      driver_ssn,
      exam_score,
      lag(exam_score) over (partition by driver_ssn order by exam_date) as prev_exam_score
    from exams
  ) to_compare
  where exam_score >= prev_exam_score
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` to see where the previous score is *bigger*.  Then use aggregation to be sure this never happens:

```
select driver_ssn
from (select e.*,
             lag(exam_score) over (partition by driver_ssn order by exam_date) as prev_exam_score
      from exams e
     ) e
group by Driver_ssn
having sum(prev_exam_score >= exam_score) = 0;
```

That is, there are no cases where the previous exam score is greater than or equal to the next one.